# Add group by field of DATE and FROM_UNIXTIME in jooq

Tags: java, jooq

Is there any way to add a group by field of:

`DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(myField))`

Using jooq 3.2.0? I've been looking through the API, searching, and can't see a way. Even if it's a custom string I'll take it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the only way I can find is to define a custom field, which is a subclass of `GroupField` and will work:

```java
query.addGroupBy( DSL.field("DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch)") );
```

Comment: That is the correct way to do it, as I've just shown in another Stack Overflow answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860383/521799. Explicit support for such Oracle-specific functions will probably be added in jOOQ 3.3: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2832

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll have to manually tweak this when we add support for additional databases, so I'll find a way to organize it in our code that makes it obvious. Side question - is there a way to get the debug values of the query? I wrote a custom listener per the logging listener example but there's no timings methods I can see. I also want to see how fast jooq itself is, so I may need an external timer

Comment: I'm not quite sure what debug values you are referring to. Maybe you could ask another question, with some more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I have this thing in my code:

```
private Field<Timestamp> fromUnixtime(Field<Long> f) {
    return DSL.function("FROM_UNIXTIME", Timestamp.class, f);
}

public someMethod() {
    // ... 

    query.addGroupBy(fromUnixTime(TABLE.EPOCH));

    // ...
}
```

1. `DSL.function()` is a thing that exists (though probably not in 2013?) and I like it.
2. `fromUnixTime()` gets a lot of reuse in my code, but it is also pretty.