# How to use toChar function in JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have to use `toChar()` function in `JOOQ`? Right now i have used below code

```
 TO_CHAR(PaymentDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')");
```

Which i have to convert into `JOOQ`. How to use this in `JOOQ`?

Answer (score 4):

Oracle's `TO_CHAR()` function is not explicitly supported by jOOQ 3.2. I have added a feature request for this: [#2832](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2832).

In the mean time, you will have to resort to plain SQL [as documented in the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/). For instance, you could write:

```java
// Create reusable fields:
Field<String> f = DSL.field(
    "TO_CHAR({0}, 'YYYY-MM-DD')", String.class, T.PaymentDate);

// Create reusable conditions:
Condition c = DSL.condition(
    "TO_CHAR({0}, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')", 
    T.PaymentDate);
```

Note that `{0}` is a reference to the first `QueryPart` argument of [`DSL.condition(String, QueryPart...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#condition%28java.lang.String,%20org.jooq.QueryPart...%29), for instance.

Comment: TO_CHAR did not make it into jOOQ 3.3. The feature request has moved to https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3064

Comment: @Thilo: Technically, that's a different feature request. We had implemented [`OracleDSL.toChar()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.3.x/org/jooq/util/oracle/OracleDSL.html#toChar-org.jooq.Field-) at the time... But you're right - from a dialect-agnostic point of view, that feature is still missing in jOOQ. We'll have to investigate and spend some time to see how this function is supported across all database vendors

Comment: In my case, I needed H2.formatDateTime. The plain SQL workaround worked well, thanks. (And that formatDateTime itself was a workaround for H2's missing support to truncate a date to a month, maybe date truncation is easier to implement across vendors than generic toChar functionality. I imagine you can put very complex things into that format String).

Comment: @Thilo: The complexity might not really matter. We also support regex predicates, whose syntax come in [very different flavours across vendors](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#likeRegex-java.lang.String-). All we care about is the parameter semantics, not the content, in these cases. H2 date truncation is currently not supported via [`DSL.trunc(date, datePart)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#trunc-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.DatePart-). I've registered [#3781](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3781) as a reminder for jOOQ 3.6 to emulate this

Comment: Hey, I now run in Jooq 3.11, was this feature ever added?

Comment: @needoriginalname: No, this was not a priority in the past years.