# How to Handle Date in Jooq?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

When we are using plain JDBC connection we are using below code to format date or convert date

```
 if(argDB.equals("Oracle")){
       sb.append(" AND TO_CHAR(PaymentDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')");
          }
 else {
       sb.append(" AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), PaymentDate, 112) <= CONVERT(varchar(8), dbo.getdate(), 112)");
           }
```

Now we are using `JOOQ` Do you think we have to convert date like we did previously or `JOOQ` can handle this type of problem internally.? As i checked right now `JOOQ` not supported `TO_CHAR` method of Oracle and Lukas given some alternative of this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855761/how-to-use-tochar-function-in-jooq/19860383#19860383)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### A better way to write your predicate

Since you're formatting dates only to compare them, you should probably just compare the date values themselves, which will be much faster as your database will be able to use an index:

```sql
-- In SQL
ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.PAYMENT_DATE <= SYSDATE
```

```java
// In jOOQ
ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.PAYMENT_DATE.le(DSL.currentDate())
```

#### Implementing a dialect-independent custom `TO_CHAR()` function.

You should create a [`CustomField`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts/) for this purpose. This will allow you to interact with jOOQ's query rendering and variable binding lifecycle in order to render SQL dialect specific clauses depending on the [`RenderContext`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/RenderContext.html)'s underlying [`SQLDialect`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html). Essentially this boils down to writing (assuming jOOQ 3.2 API):

```java
class ToChar extends CustomField<String> {
    final Field<?> arg0;
    final Field<?> arg1;
    ToChar(Field<?> arg0, Field<?> arg1) {
        super("to_char", SQLDataType.VARCHAR);
        this.arg0 = arg0;
        this.arg1 = arg1;
    }
    @Override
    public void toSQL(RenderContext context) {
        context.visit(delegate(context.configuration()));
    }
    @Override
    public void bind(BindContext context) {
        context.visit(delegate(context.configuration()));
    }
    private QueryPart delegate(Configuration configuration) {
        switch (configuration.dialect().family()) {
            case ORACLE:
                return DSL.field("TO_CHAR({0}, {1})", 
                    String.class, arg0, arg1);

            case SQLSERVER:
                return DSL.field("CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), {0}, {1})", 
                    String.class, arg0, arg1);

            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Dialect not supported");
        }
    }
}
```

And then, you can write your own static utility methods as such:

```java
public class MyDSL {
    public static Field<String> toChar(Field<?> field, String format) {
        return new ToChar(field, DSL.inline(format));
    }
}
```

Comment: It mean JOOQ will not handle Date interally we have to write this code?Second this this was my select query where i used above code and its part of addCondition

Comment: As I mentioned [in the other answer that you've linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860383/521799), jOOQ currently doesn't support and standardise Oracle's `TO_CHAR()` and similar functions. The above is your best approach, if you want to implement such support yourself. This way, you can extend jOOQ. On the other hand, why not just compare date values instead of formatting them first?

Comment: Ok thanks You mean something ike this? '  selectQueryPayment.addConditions(AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.PAYMENT_DATE.lessOrEqual(DateTimeUtils.getTodayNow())); Field PAYMENT_DATE is in Timestamp and my Utils also return Timestamp it will handle directly
'

Comment: Yes, depending on your available date precision, this might be a better solution, even in SQL. I've also updated my answer...