# How to generate to_date in jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

how to generate a sql with to_date in jooq:

```
select * from mytable where TIME_ACTIVE >= 
    to_date('2011-01-02 00:00:00.000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

Answer (score 1):

nevermind, figured it out

create a custom jooq field:

```
static class ToDate extends CustomField<String> {
           String arg0=null;
           String arg1=null;
           ToDate(String arg0, String arg1) {
               super("to_date", SQLDataType.VARCHAR);
               this.arg0 = arg0;
               this.arg1 = arg1;
           }

           @Override
           public void toSQL(RenderContext context) {
               context.visit(delegate(context.configuration()));
           }
           @Override
           public void bind(BindContext context) {
               context.visit(delegate(context.configuration()));
           }
           private QueryPart delegate(Configuration configuration) {
                       return DSL.field("TO_DATE({0}, {1})",
                                String.class, arg0, arg1);
           }
        }
```

then call it with something like:

```
case "DATE":
    return new ToDate((String)object,"yyyy-MM-dd");
case "TIMESTAMP":
    return new ToDate((String)object,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

this answer was helpful: [How to Handle Date in Jooq?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19900607/165130)

Comment: That's one solution, but you don't really need to wrap that in a class of its own. You could also just simply use the plain SQL solution from your `delegate()` method...